# Angular 11: I can't display a pdf

Tags: html, angular, typescript, pdf, base64

I am trying to display a string in Base64 to PDF and download it in the browser, when I send the variable that owns it, it does not show it in the browser.

app.component.html ->

```html
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3 style="font-size: 1.2em; color: #838181" class="modal-title" id="modal-title">
    {{ terminosCondicionesModalSeguroVidaTitulo }}
  </h3>
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-describedby="modal-title" (click)="close()">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
   
    <iframe width='100%' height='100%' src=''>{{SeguroVida}}</iframe>
   
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <input type="submit" class="btnGenericGreen next" (click)="Aprobar()"
    value="{{ terminosCondicionesModalSeguroVidaBoton }}" />
</div>
```

app.component.ts ->

```js
llenadoParametros() {
  console.log(this.paramArray.find((x) => x.codigo === DocumentsAcceptation.SeguroVida) ? .valorAlfa || '');
  this.SeguroVida = this.paramArray.find(
    (x) => x.codigo === DocumentsAcceptation.SeguroVida
  ) ? .valorAlfa || '';

  this.SeguroVida = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:application/pdf;base64,' + this.paramArray.find((x) => x.codigo === DocumentsAcceptation.SeguroVida) ? .valorAlfa || '');
}
```

I still don't know why it doesn't show it in the browser. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set src to iframe.

```
<iframe width='100%' height='100%' [src]='SeguroVida'></iframe>
```